# how to hande multiple clients in server when reading and writing to a file

Tags: php

I have a php page, that when visited, it will open a txt file, read from it, and then write to it. But what happens if multiple people visit the php page at the same time? Is there a way to wait until the file is not being used before the php code read/writes to it? Sort of add synchronization to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temp files for each user. Once the user completes his action and logs out. You can create a function to read the temp file's content and put it to the original file and later delete the temp file.